# If child is removed from the stage, all the event listeners related to him will be removed also?

Tags: flash, actionscript

So i am asking if i need to write removeEventListener, or when i write removeChild - all the related animation from this child will be removed? like this:

```
displayObject.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
displayObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.click, onClick)

and so on...
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to remove the event listeners. Otherwise the objects will not get removed from memory.

You can get around this by using weakly referenced listeners.
This means that when all other references to an object are removed, the event listeners will not prevent the object from getting garbage-collected.

See this article for more info:
http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/07/as3_weakly_refe.html